# Why AVG function perform the SUM?

Tags: sum, mdx, average

I would to execute a query with a calculated member which returns the AVG (of the measure) of the Coil belonging to a particular LINESPEED.

The query is:

```
With
Member [Measures].[Avg1] As
AVG(
([LINESPEED].currentmember,
[GRUPPO].[Coil].currentmember)
,
[Measures].[KPI1]
)    
SELECT [Measures].[Avg1] on 0,
non empty {[LINESPEED].children} On 1 
from[HDGL]
```

But the AVG function compute exactly the sum of the KPIs of the coil related to a particular LINESPEED!!

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is using a single tuple, so AVG() is equivalent to SUM() :

```
AVG( ([LINESPEED].currentmember, [GRUPPO].[Coil].currentmember), ...)
```